# How to model this in a flexible and nondestructive way?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, procedural

I need to model this shape in a way that makes the general shape of the brackets easily editable, without having to extensive re-model and move many vertices each time I need to change the shape. I've tried tons of approaches using nearly every modifier and tool in blender's toolkit, but just cant seem to come to a workable solution. Desperately looking for an effective solution for this! Here are some of the shapes I need to be able to create with this setup (these renders were done using a displacement modifier and height maps that I generated in after effects, but would love to be able to maintain the entire workflow in Blender):

[image]

Comment: This looks fairly easy to do with an armature and some shrink wrap. Aside: Please do not say you’ve tried “everything,” since it will potentially dismotivate any suggestions as they may or may not be in “everything.” It basically says to helpers that they have no hope of helping.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Thats why i said NEARLY everything ;) looking for someone's fresh take - thanks for the response; Could you elaborate on how you'd use an armature and shrinkwrap?

Answer (score 1):

Make the bracket shapes, and set up an armature to deform them. Maybe just make one bracket and use a mirror modifier to copy it after it’s been deformed. Next, make a heavily subdivided plane, and put it where it would be if it was over the bracket’s location but they weren’t there. Use the shrink wrap modifier on the plane, and I think there is a setting where you can tell it to only deform along a certain axis, and make sure it stays outside of the target mesh.

Comment: gotcha - and if I needed to be able to change the radius of the corners, how could I do that? weight painting?

Comment: When does it have to change? Inside the animation?